# Corona SDK drawing lines using circles

Tags: android, ios, lua, coronasdk

I have this code to draw a line on the screen using display.newCircle. it works perfectly but
as i draw more it will be more unstable and leaks memory.
How can i keep this optimized.
The problem is only on the device.
Here is the code

```
local background = display.newRect( 0, 0, 480, 800 )

local lines = {};
local i = 1;
local strokeWidth = 20;
local R = 150;
local G = 100; 
local B = 50;

local function drawALine(event) 
    if event.phase == "began" then
    elseif event.phase == "moved" then

        lines[i] = display.newCircle(event.x, event.y, strokeWidth, strokeWidth);
        lines[i]:setFillColor( R,G,B );

    elseif event.phase == "ended" then
    end     
end
Runtime:addEventListener("touch", drawALine)
```

Any help?

Comment: What do you mean by unstable?

Comment: Is this your main.lua? You don't use scenes or createScene event?

Comment: no it is not main.lua i use director class to change from scene to scene i have added in group like this `lines[i] = display.newCircle(paintGroup, event.x, event.y, strokeWidth, strokeWidth);` but this don't change anything

Comment: and by unstable i mean my app is not responding after some time of drawing.

Comment: Please consider extending your question with info instead of putting in comments, it helps make a better question and people don't have to read zillion comments.

Comment: Re unstable and "not responding after some time": clarify in your answer, does it completely hang and you have to kill it? or does it take longer for new circle to appear every time you touch the screen? Can you put a counter and indicate value of counter? Can you put an enterFrame event handler in which you compute how long since last enterFrame, this way you can measure framerate. Please put all this (and info from above comments) in your question.

Comment: it take longer for new circle to appear every time i touch the screen

Answer (score 0):

Every time you touch the screen you extend your line of circles with one more circle but you don't add it to the scene view so it is not managed by scene.

Comment: You mean addind to group? I have added to group like this                          `lines[i] = display.newCircle(paintGroup, event.x, event.y, strokeWidth, strokeWidth);` but this don't change anything

Comment: no, the scene view group. You don't use a createScene(event) callback?

Comment: I use director class for the scene not stroryboard

Comment: I doubt this is related to your problem but just wanted to point out that your newCircle should take 3 parameters (x,y,radius), not 4 (this is available but only when first parameter is the group to add to). Stroke width should be set via strokeWidth parameter (http://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/graphics/path.html).

Answer (score 0):

Where do you increment the variable i?  If you don't you are writing over the previous entry, but it's still allocating memory.  You can put some prints in your code to watch your memory to see if it's getting too high.